# confirm package uploaded to cran

Tags: r, package

I used this code from the command prompt on a windows box (linux machine is at work):

```
ftp -u ftp://cran.R-project.org/incoming/ qdap_0.1.0.tar.gz
```

I used the info from:

https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Release
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Submitting-a-package-to-CRAN

I expected to see it show up here: ftp://cran.r-project.org/incoming/ but I do not see it.

Am I just being impatient or did my package not upload?  Here is the command line output:

```
C:\Users\trinker\GitHub>ftp -u ftp://cran.R-project.org/incoming/ qdap_0.1.0.tar
.gz

Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service
(sometimes called a daemon). Ftp can be used interactively.

FTP [-v] [-d] [-i] [-n] [-g] [-s:filename] [-a] [-A] [-x:sendbuffer] [-r:recvbuf
fer] [-b:asyncbuffers] [-w:windowsize] [host]

  -v              Suppresses display of remote server responses.
  -n              Suppresses auto-login upon initial connection.
  -i              Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file
                  transfers.
  -d              Enables debugging.
  -g              Disables filename globbing (see GLOB command).
  -s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
                  commands will automatically run after FTP starts.
  -a              Use any local interface when binding data connection.
  -A              login as anonymous.
  -x:send sockbuf Overrides the default SO_SNDBUF size of 8192.
  -r:recv sockbuf Overrides the default SO_RCVBUF size of 8192.
  -b:async count  Overrides the default async count of 3
  -w:windowsize   Overrides the default transfer buffer size of 65535.
  host            Specifies the host name or IP address of the remote
                  host to connect to.

Notes:
  - mget and mput commands take y/n/q for yes/no/quit.
  - Use Control-C to abort commands.
```

Comment: Make sure you are not looking at a page cached earlier by your browser.  From Windows you might want to try FileZilla to upload and concurrently see the directory uploaded to.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck The filezilla worked and was confirmed here: http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass/branches/develbranch_6/mswindows/external/rbatch/RESOURCES  Can you add as an answer so I can check for future searchers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This was previously a comment and is being transferred to an answer here.)

1. Make sure you are not looking at a page cached earlier by your browser.
2. To perform the actual upload you might want to try the free cross platform [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) FTP software.  You can [upload and concurrently view](http://filezilla-project.org/images/screenshots/fz3_win_main.png) the contents of the source directory on your machine (in the left pane) and the target directory on CRAN (in the right pane) and view a log of what is happening in the top pane and a progress indicator in the bottom pane.  It also has a [site manager](http://filezilla-project.org/images/screenshots/fz3_win_sitemanager.png) to store the sites you upload to so you don't need to keep typing in their URL each time you do an upload.